# Run configuration issue when running Scala in Eclipse for the first time

Tags: eclipse, scala

I am trying to run a scala project for the first time in eclipse. I have selected "Scala" in perspective. I am having trouble with configuring my run for scala.

My project name is `scala_try` and in the project folder I have:
`src` -> `scala_try` -> `Demo.scala`

When I right-click on `Demo.scala` and try to run it, I have:
`Run As -> Run Configurations...`

How do I configure my run for scala here?

I tried: `Scala-Application -> New_configuration` but when I search for Main Class, there is nothing matched.

If I just go on and write `Demo` as Main class, after running I get this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main
```

my code in `Demo.scala`:

```
package scala_try

object Demo extends App{
def main(args: Array[String]) {
  print("Hola!");
 }
}
```

Any sort of help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just try removing either of these code

```
package scala_try

object Demo {
def main(args: Array[String]) {
  print("Hola!");
 }
}
```

OR

```
package scala_try

object Demo extends App{
 print("Hola!");
}
```

Using `extends App` and `main` method together in a object generally causes this issue as per my opinion.